# Automatically 'closing' the $ symbol in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

Friends, is there a way to make TeXstudio 'close' the `$` symbol the same way it does with parenthesis or even `\(`?

Comment: You can press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`m` simultaneouly to get `$  $`?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a new macro using the keyboard shortcut `$`.

[image: Macro for double dollar sign]

This will automatically insert `$$` when you enter one `$`. The `%|` places the cursor between the dollar signs, so you can immediately start writing your equation.

Comment: Excellent answer! This works